# Public listing of newsletters in Joomla?

Tags: civimail, joomla, newsletter

On a Joomla site we would like to allow the public to see a list of newsletters sent through CiviMail. Subject of email would be the link text, body of newsletter including images would be displayed as a site page when clicked. So, similar to a Drupal view like in [How can I show users the mailings they have been sent?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7550/how-can-i-show-users-the-mailings-they-have-been-sent)

What's a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

a bit late on this one. It's not an ideal solution, but a quick fix could be AcyMailing which has a CiviCRM plugin and front-end newsletter listings. https://www.acyba.com/acymailing/390-acymailing-plugin-civicrm.html